# Отправка медиафайлов ботом ТГ

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Занялся изучением процесса написания ботов в ТГ. Пишу пока самое простой, просто эхобот который отвечает на сообщения. Сделал кнопочки меню при нажатии на которые присылается разный текст или открываются подменю и спокнулся на таком вопросе. Как сделать так, что бы бот кроме текста отправлял изображение.

```
    async def text_button (message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('подменю', reply_markup=keyboard2)
    await message.answer_photo(InputFile('media/1.jpg'))
```

пишет

```
await message.answer_photo(InputFile('media/1.jpg')) 

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class InputFile with abstract method read
```

Если

```
async def text_button (message: types.Message):
    await message.answer('подменю', reply_markup=keyboard2)
    await message.answer_photo('media/1.jpg')
```

то требует ссылку на фото в интернете.

```
  await Bot.send_photo(chat_id=message.from_user.id, photo=open('media/1.jpg', 'rb'))
```

не видит файл

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'media/1.jpg'
```

А как сделать что бы он брал фото из папки media? Что я не так делаю?
Куда в интернете не смотрел, все учат отправлять текст, а вот с картинками не могу разобраться...

Comment: Читать документацию и смотреть [примеры](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram/blob/dev-2.x/examples/media_group.py) - не наш метод?

Comment: А еще замените `media/1.jpg` на `'media\\1.jpg`

Comment: Просто на всякий случай уточню перед тем как уйти дальше искать ответ. message.answer_photo это ответить на изображение или ответить изображением?